# SQL Server 2012 new feature Sequence

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sequence

Is there any possibility to generate sequence number from  initial value 1 for each table using with one sequence(every table should start with 1 using one sequence like identity)? And why do we need sequences?

I have used below script,

```
--Create the Test schema  
CREATE SCHEMA Test ;  
GO  

-- Create a table  
CREATE TABLE Test.Orders  
    (OrderID int PRIMARY KEY,  
    Name varchar(20) NOT NULL,  
    Qty int NOT NULL);  
GO  



-- Create a sequence  
CREATE SEQUENCE Test.TestSequence
    START WITH 1  
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;  
GO  

-- Insert three records  
INSERT Test.Orders (OrderID, Name, Qty)  

    VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR Test.TestSequence, 'One', 2) ; 

INSERT test.Orders (OrderID, Name, Qty)  

    VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR Test.TestSequence, 'Two', 1) ; 

INSERT test.Orders (OrderID, Name, Qty)  

    VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR Test.TestSequence, 'Three', 1) ;  
GO  

-- View the table  
SELECT * FROM Test.Orders ;  
GO

    CREATE TABLE Test.Employee  
    (EmpId int PRIMARY KEY,  
    EmpName varchar(20) NOT NULL,  
    DeptId int NOT NULL,
    Sal Decimal(15,2));  
GO  
insert into Test.Employee (EmpId,EmpName,DeptId,Sal) values

(NEXT VALUE FOR Test.TestSequence,'One',1,45000),

(NEXT VALUE FOR Test.TestSequence,'Two',2,54000),

(NEXT VALUE FOR Test.TestSequence,'Three',3,60000),

(NEXT VALUE FOR Test.TestSequence,'Four',2,75000)


INSERT Test.Orders (OrderID, Name, Qty)  
    VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR Test.TestSequence, 'Four', 5) ;  

    insert into Test.Employee (EmpId,EmpName,DeptId,Sal) values

(NEXT VALUE FOR Test.TestSequence,'Five',1,90000)

select * from Test.Orders 

select * from Test.Employee
```

O/P:-

```
OrderID,    Name,   Qty
1      One      2 
2      Two      1
3     Three     1
8     Four      5

EmpId   EmpName DeptId  Sal
4   One      1      45000.00
5   Two      2      54000.00
6   Three    3      60000.00
7   Four     2      75000.00
9   Five     1      90000.00
```

Expecting result:- OrderId=1,2,3,4....

Comment: You are using the same sequence to generate numbers for a different table. Don't. If you want different numbers for a different table, use a different sequence.

Answer (score 4):

The advantage of using `Sequence` (the `identity column`cannot) is :

1. `Sequence` is not tied to any tables, while `identity` has to be created when creating tables. `Sequence` could be added later to the columns.
2. `Sequence` supports `Cyclying`feature, which could repeat number groups.
3. `Truncate` will not reset `Sequence` number.
4. You cannot update `identity` column. (directly update the identity value, not `identity_insert` )
5. as `Alex` said from the comments, `Sequence` could grant you convenience when you need keys to not conflict across different tables.

So you could use a same `Sequence` that has been created as `MinValue   1` or `Start with 1`  for any number of tables' columns.

Please note when you are using `Cyclying`, you'd better to set `MinValue` with 1 instead of `Start With`, otherwise, when `Sequence` hit `Max`, it will go back to its `Min` if you do not specify its `Min`, which will be -2147483648 for default `INT`

Comment: And the sequence allows you to assign unique numbers to different tables, which is useful, for example, in data partitioning.

Comment: FWIW, an identity will allow you repeat numbers too. You just have to reseed it. Good answer!!